# KSOAP2 webservice ilon100 smartserver

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to use Android to call echelon smartserver's web service.
I need to replace jax-ws which is not compatibile with Android. I decided to use KSOAP2.

I tried this way but without succeed:

```
public class ConnectTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button SoapButton;
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/wsdl/";
    private static String URL = "http://192.168.100.247/WSDL/v4.0/iLON100.wsdl";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "List";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/wsdl/List";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo();
propInfo.name = "iLonItem";
request.addProperty("<xSelect>//Item[@xsi:type=\"Item_Cfg\"]</xSelect>",propInfo);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try 
            {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                        .getResponse();
                SoapResponse = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
                System.out.println("SOAP" + SoapResponse);

            } catch (Exception e) 
            {

                Log.e("Error", "pb IO", e);
                SoapResponse = "error connection";
            }

            return SoapResponse;
```

It ends up with following console error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: iLonItem : (not set)
```

What I should do to correct send below message using SOAP? Of course using KSOAP2.

```
   <List xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
<iLonItem>
<xSelect>//Item[@xsi:type=\"Item_Cfg\"]</xSelect>
</iLonItem>
</List>
```

Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are a couple of things that need to change.

First, The namespace that is expected is `"http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/"`

this is found in this line of code you provided

`<List xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">`

Second, I believe you have the properties switched around.  iLonItem is the property name and should go first in the `request` call like this

```
request.addProperty("iLonItem","<xSelect>//Item[@xsi:type=\"Item_Cfg\"]</xSelect>" );
```

As for the value, I have no idea what "//Item[@xsi:type=\"Item_Cfg\"]" means, but hopefully it should recognize the request and do what it is supposed to with that.

Comment: Do you know what the request structure is?  It should look something like what I mention above

Comment: The message I would like to send (at the bottom of my first post) is an example from Programmers Reference guide given by the server manufacturer

Comment: That was helpful, I believe I found some of the issues.  let me know if it works